# Loop with respect to # of API calls and time interval

Tags: vba, loops

I make a bunch of API calls to a website that limits the # of API calls per hour.  Because I make, sometimes, 100k+ number of calls, it'll sometimes take hours to get all the data I need.  I want to built a loop that checks if API calls exceeds the max number per hour, and if I have exceeded, check the time difference between when I started and now.  Something like

```
startTime = Now()

For i = 1 To 150000
    If counter <= 36000 Then
        url = baseURL + Str(i) + "?apikey=" + apiKey
        resp.Open "GET", url
        resp.Send

        ' Process the response

        counter = counter + 1
    Else # More than 36,000 API calls have been made
        Do
            # Nothing in the loop, just waiting for 60 minutes to pass
        While DateDiff(n, startTime, Now()) < 60

        startTime = Now()
        i = i - 1 # Need to re-loop on the current i
    End If
Next i
```

I haven't had an opportunity to test it yet, but on paper it looks like it'll work, but also looks like a hack job (especially that i = i - 1).  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: As Comintern pointed out I missed the I counter.

Every time the counter reaches the 36000 mark I would check to see if a hour has passed.  If it hasn't I would reset the start time and continue else I would schedule the Macro to run again 1 hour after the start time.

```
 Sub MakeAPICalls(Optional Counter As Long = 150000)

    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Dim count As Long

    For I = Counter To 150000

        count = count + 1

        URL = baseURL + Str(I) + "?apikey=" + apiKey
        resp.Open "GET", URL
        resp.Send

        ' Process the response
        ' Exit Do if complete

        If (count Mod 36000) = 0 Then
            If (Timer - Start) < 3600 Then
                Start = Timer
            Else
                Application.OnTime Now + (3600 - (Timer - Start)), "MakeAPICalls " & I
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Like the `OnTime` call, but shouldn't `count` be static?

Comment: The counter and timer can reset because the sub will not be called again till the hour is up.  The part that might need to be static is the OP's code.  I have no way of telling when he has collected all the data.  The OP will have to structure his code, in such a way, that running the Macro multiple times will still yield the desired result.

Comment: Makes sense. The OP has `Str([loopcounter])` built into the URL. I was just thinking that it would be easier to reuse the `count`.

Comment: @Comintern Thank you.  How did I miss that!!  Please review my updated answer.

Comment: What took so long?  You got my +1 almost a hour ago!! ..LOL, I just wanted to make sure that I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Hello, OP here.  This looks good but I think I'm going to have to modify it a bit... If I've hit 36k API calls before the hour is up I need to start the next iteration of the macro at 36001.  The way it's written right now the I variable will be overwritten and the loop will start back at one.

Correct me if I'm wrong though!  I've been out of the VBA game a long time.

Comment: Thank you again Thomas. My apologies for not marking your answer as correct sooner!

Comment: No worries. My apologies for not getting it right the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify this by using 2 nested loops.  Step the outer loop by your request count, then use the inner loop to make your 36K requests:

```
Dim requests As Long
For i = 1 To 150000 Step 36000
    If i > 144000 Then requests = 5999 Else requests = 35999
    For x = 0 To requests
        URL = baseURL + Str(i + x) + "?apikey=" + apiKey
        resp.Open "GET", URL
        resp.Send
        ' Process the response
    Next
    Sleep 3600000 '1 hour
Next
```

Note this uses the `Sleep` API call:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

This will make sure your processor isn't pegged at 100% for an hour in a do nothing loop.  If you want Excel to remain responsive (`Sleep` literally pauses the thread it's running on), you can put a `DoEvents` inside your NOP loop, but it's still going to be a ton of wasted CPU cycles.

Comment: Okay, I miss read your last statement. I think that `Sleep 1000:DoEvents` would be nice compromise.  `Sleep 3600000` should probably be adjusted to account for the time it took to get to 36K calls (If it takes 59 minutes to process 36K calls, the Macro should pause for 1 minute).